# Load drawable from arraylist using Lazy Image Loader or Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, android-drawable, universal-image-loader

I just want to ask, is that possible to load drawable from arraylist inside arrays.xml using Lazy Image Loader or Universal Image Loader?

First load arraylist of drawable

```
....

ArrayList<Integer> sample_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

....

Resources resources = getResources();
String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();
final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(R.array.sample);

    for (String extra : extras) {
       int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
       if (res != 0) {
           sample_list.add(res);
    }
}
```

Set drawable to imageview

```
imageView.setImageResource(sample_list.get(position));
```

Last time I used like above, but I want to use Lazy Image Loader or Universal Image loader

I dont use any url to load image

So is that possible?

If possible is there any sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is not recommending for loading the images in drawable... You should use native method

Since u r using arraylist if u r saving the image name ids u can use like

`String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;`

(here this.R.drawable.image would be ur arraylist value.

**NOTE:From: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
they are recommending to use native method if u want to show images from drawable**

```
imageview.setImageResources(res id);
```

Comment: But I want to set image from arraylist which contains a lot of drawable. At the moment I'm using CustomAdapter to display it, but that's eating a lot of memory ...

So that's not possible?

Comment: u can use image uri. i updated my ans, what is the necessory to use imageloader for this?

Comment: So I need to define all of my drawable from arraylist? Can I do like

String imageUri = "drawable://" -- get the id from arraylist based on it's position -- ?

Comment: first tel me what is the need to show drawable images using imageloader?

Comment: As I said before, I tried to display using ArrayAdapter, but loads so slow, even I have decode the drawable to Bitmap. I'm trying to display a lot of drawable, all of drawable only have resolution 96x96 pixels.

I just trying to find another way

Comment: This is the reason why I'm trying to use Imageloader [stackoverflow- question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598701/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-items-in-gridview)

Comment: Okay u can save the id's into the arraylist and use the imageURI to get the uri inside the adapter and load the image using imageloader.

Comment: If possible, could you please give an example how to get the id based on the position? Please ...

Comment: I mean like get imageURI from the id that I saved inside arraylist

Comment: u r using imageView.setImageResource(sample_list.get(position)); inside adapter now, instead of that inside adapter u r going to set the imageUri and use that imageUri with imageloader , can u understand?